# Proper use of CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax

Some programmers use floats like this

```
CGFloat itemsHeight = [m_subscriptions count] * 97.f;
```

and some use floats like this

```
CGFloat itemsHeight = [m_subscriptions count] * 97.0f;
```

Is there any side affect in dropping the zero?

Comment: You can drop the zero, the decimal point, and the `f` and it won't matter in this case.

Comment: I suppose that is due to the implicit cast on assignment. good eye

Comment: Don't forget that on 64-bit architectures (which constitute most iOS and OS X devices these days), `CGFloat` is typedef'ed to a C `double` (not a `float`). So, you should omit the `f` altogether because it's not doing anything and your number often will be stored in a double anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, trailing zeros make no difference: the value of your floating point constant would remain the same. You do need a dot in there, because otherwise the compiler would report a syntax error. In other words, `[m_subscriptions count] * 97f` will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

There's no side effect. Those are both literal notations for the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use 0.0, .0, or 0.0f or even 0f does not make much of a difference. (There are some with respect to double and float)

If you are initializing a variable then it make no sense. compiler does all the cast for you.

```
float a = 0; //Cast int 0 to float 0.0
float b = 0.0; //Cast 0.0 double to float 0.0 as by default floating point constants are double
float c = 0.0f // Assigning float to float. .0f is same as 0.0f
```

But if you are using these in an expression then that make a lot of sense.

6/5 becomes 1
6/5.0 becomes 1.2 (double value)
6/5.0f becomes 1.2 (float value)

so the basic difference is as :

1.0 or 1. is a double constant
1.0f is a float constant

Without a suffix, a literal with a decimal in it (199.0) will be treated as a double-precision floating-point number. If you assign or pass that to a single-precision variable or parameter, the compiler will (should) issue a warning. Appending f tells the compiler you want the literal to be treated as a single-precision floating-point number.

Comment: you should also use CGFloat rather than float so the compiler uses the correct data type for 32 bit(float) vs. 64 bit(double)